# C++: get error: std::bad_alloc when using vector and iterator

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am using [mailio library](https://github.com/karastojko/mailio) and I get into trouble when I want to get all elements in a vector.

```
string msg = "Subject: " + mail -> subject() + "\nFrom: ";
for(auto address = ( mail -> from() ).addresses.begin(); address != ( mail -> from() ).addresses.end(); ++address ){ //address is not empty
    msg.append( address -> name );//     <----here
}
```

Here are the brief definations of class `message`:

```
class MAILIO_EXPORT message : public mime
{
...
public:
    mailboxes from() const;
...
}

struct MAILIO_EXPORT mailboxes
{
    ...
    std::vector<mail_address> addresses;
    ...
}

struct MAILIO_EXPORT mail_address
{
    ...
    std::string name;
    ...
}
```

The program terminates and returns `get error: std::bad_alloc`. I don't know what's wrong, though I still managed to solved it with following code:

```
string msg = "Subject: " + mail -> subject() + "\nFrom: ";
auto add = ( mail -> from() ).addresses; 
for(auto address = add.begin(); address != add.end(); ++address ){
     msg.append( address -> name );
}
```

Maybe I tried to modify one or some of these const values unconsciously. But I am not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Also what does `mail -> from()` return?  Is it a copy of an object, or a reference to an existing object?  Look at your code to see the issue with that `for` loop.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333002/stdbad-alloc-whit-stdvector-tic-tac-toe).  Return a reference if you want to refer to the original `mailboxes`, not a copy of `mailboxes`.

Comment: Due to my poor knowledge, `from()` seems to return a copy but the behavior is accordant to you two saying. I suppose that the `begin` and `end` are not refer to the same `( mail -> from() ).addresses`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `from()` doesn’t return a reference then it makes a copy of the struct, including copying the `std::vector`. This means in your loop you get *two different* vectors of which you take `begin()` and `end()` respectively. You’re not allowed to loop between these since the begin iterator will most likely never match the end, especially before going out of bounds.

In the second code there’s one copy and you use iterators from it so they will work.